# Array algorithm too slow

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, for-loop

i have written an algorithm that finds each line of a hexagon in a huge object-array structure.

the array consits of about 80.000 - 100.000 elements (line coordinates from start to end).

A hexagon cosists of 6 lines points. So the array has the information of about 15.000 hexagons.

The structure of the object (UNSORTED!!!) looks like this:

```
const stamps = [
  { 
    vertices: [
      {x: 114.5116411118, y: 342.9815785601},
      {x: 115.6663416502, y: 344.9815785601}
    ]
  },
  {
    vertices: [
      {x: 115.6663416502, y: 340.9815785601},
      {x: 114.5116411118, y: 342.9815785601}
    ]
  },
  {
    vertices: [
      {x: 122.6663416502, y: 364.9815785601},
      {x: 147.9757427269, y: 314.9815785601},
    ]
  },
  {
    vertices: [
      {x: 117.9757427269, y: 340.9815785601},
      {x: 115.6663416502, y: 340.9815785601},
    ]
  },
  {
    vertices: [
      {x: 119.1304432653, y: 342.9815785601},
      {x: 117.9757427269, y: 340.9815785601},
    ]
  },
  {
    vertices: [
      {x: 117.9757427269, y: 344.9815785601},
      {x: 119.1304432653, y: 342.9815785601},
    ]
  },
  {
    vertices: [
      {x: 115.6663416502, y: 344.9815785601},
      {x: 117.9757427269, y: 344.9815785601},
    ]
  },
];
```

To find each line hexagon, my idea was that there has to be 2 elements that have to same coordinate. If this is the case, i'm jumping to the index of this element and repeat that process untill i have all 6 lines of the hexagon.

It works like this, but its really, really slow. For an array with 80.000 elements its about 3 minutes.

The algorithm:

```
function findHexPolyPoints() {
  const hexCoordinates = [];
  let activeArrayPos = 0;
  let position = 0;
  while (1) {
    let foundPair = false;
    if (stamps.length < 6) break;
    for (let k = 0; k < stamps.length; ++k) {
      if (k === position) continue;
      if (stamps[position].vertices[0].x === stamps[k].vertices[1].x && stamps[position].vertices[0].y === stamps[k].vertices[1].y) {
        if (hexCoordinates[activeArrayPos]) {
          hexCoordinates[activeArrayPos].push(stamps[k].vertices[0].x, stamps[k].vertices[0].y);
        } else {
          hexCoordinates.push([stamps[position].vertices[0].x, stamps[position].vertices[0].y, stamps[k].vertices[0].x, stamps[k].vertices[0].y]);
        }
        foundPair = true;
      } else if (stamps[position].vertices[1].x === stamps[k].vertices[0].x && stamps[position].vertices[1].y === stamps[k].vertices[0].y) {
        if (hexCoordinates[activeArrayPos]) {
          hexCoordinates[activeArrayPos].push(stamps[k].vertices[1].x, stamps[k].vertices[1].y);
        } else {
          hexCoordinates.push([stamps[position].vertices[1].x, stamps[position].vertices[1].y, stamps[k].vertices[1].x, stamps[k].vertices[1].y]);
        }
        foundPair = true;
      }
      if (foundPair) {
        stamps.splice(position, 1);
        if (k > position) {
          position = k - 1;
        } else {
          position = k;
        }
        if (hexCoordinates[activeArrayPos].length < 12) break;
      }
      if (hexCoordinates[activeArrayPos] && hexCoordinates[activeArrayPos].length === 12) {
        if (k > position) stamps.splice(k - 1, 1);
        else stamps.splice(k, 1);
        activeArrayPos += 1;
        position = 0;
        break;
      }
      if (k === stamps.length - 1) {
        stamps.splice(position, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  sortHexagons(hexCoordinates);
}
```

Is there any way to speed up my algorithm? I have read that a simple for loop is still faster that some js sort functions like .`map` .`filter` or similar.

Comment: So what query contains  -line? coordinate? What should be an answer?

Comment: what does sortHexagons do? Also, do all the hexagons have the same vertex co-ordinates?

Comment: @WillJenkins
thats pretty much irrelevant. i'm just sorting the array afterwards.

Comment: When I scroll down, wow, I don't want to read your code. The cyclomatic complexity is very high

Comment: again... do the hexagons have the same vertex co-ordinates or if not, how many different sets are there?

Comment: and what's the output you need? a count of hexagons? an array of found hexagons?

Comment: @David Assuming this is to do with hexagonal tiles, [Hexagonal Grids](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) has plenty of information that might be of use to you.

Comment: @WillJenkins
yes. there are always 2 lines that have the same vertex coordinates. the output is an array of subarrays. each subarrays contains all coordinates of a hexagon (12 entries, x and y).

Comment: Do you have a test set/way to generate test data that can be used?

Comment: @AlexVestin
i updated the dummy data in the question. you should be able to find 1 hexagon now from this set.

Comment: Don't know how the data was generated, but did you account for floating point inaccuracies (I see `===` in your code), even if the difference is only `10^-10`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following O(n) algorithm assumes

1. two different hexagons do not have overlapping vertices
2. there are no more than two same vertices in the array (meaning, there could be an orphan that doesn't belong to any hexagon, but its coordinates should not equal any of the hexagons vertices)
3. there is no floating point inaccuracy in coordinates (meaning two vertices that are supposed to be equal, are `===` exactly equal)
4. 6 connected vertices are assumed to form an hexagon... (there is no barycenter calculation and checks to ensure it's actually an hexagon)

(if the points 1. and 2. are not true, the algo would need to be worked more, to try all possibilities (in `overt[x_y]` array, see below) in order to avoid non-hexagon or overlapping coords, depending on the expectancy to find overlapping hexagons, or orphans, the complexity could go beyond O(n))

Using the concept of *map* (get an object value from a key), which is considered O(1).

In order to conveniently use the vertices coordinates, we can concatenate x and y into one string

```
x:123.456, y:789.321
```

gives

```
x_y = "123.456_789.321"
```

Let's create 3 variables `avert = []`, `overt = {}`, `hexas = []`

- `avert` is an array of all vertices, `avert[index]` is an array(2) of the `x_y` vertices coordinates
- `overt` is an object that, for each `x_y` coordinates gives an array of indexes in `avert` (the size should not become more than 2, as assumed above (and there is no >2 check))
- `hexas` is an array of array(6), the list of hexagons found (each coordinate is formatted `x_y`)

In the first `forEach`, `avert` and `overt` are created.

The next `forEach` processes all `avert` vertices [x_y1, x_y2]

- starting from the first vertex, tries to find the 6 points to form an hexagon
- adds each vertex to one hexagon array `hexa`, starting from the *next* (after the first)
- assume coordinates are *not* sorted, thus ensure we're not going back to previous vertice
- skips the used vertices (in hexagons)
- ensure the last vertex found has the same coordinates as the `origin` (first)

Initialization

```
let avert = [], overt = {}, hexas = [];

stamps.forEach(function(e, i){
    let xy1 = e['vertices'][0]['x']+'_'+e['vertices'][0]['y'];
    let xy2 = e['vertices'][1]['x']+'_'+e['vertices'][1]['y'];
    // overt[XY] (array) should have two elements at most (no overlapping),
    // one if orphan
    if ( ! overt[xy1]) overt[xy1] = [];
    overt[xy1].push( i );
    if ( ! overt[xy2]) overt[xy2] = [];
    overt[xy2].push( i );
    avert.push([ xy1, xy2 ]);
});
```

Processing

```
avert.forEach(function (e){
    let j,coord = e[0];   // first coords x_y
    let origin = coord;
    let hexa = [];
    let lastindex = -1;   // avoid going back!
    // try to find 5 connected vertices + origin
    for(j=0 ; j<6 ; j++) {
        let o = overt[coord];
        if ( o === undefined || o.length < 2 ) {
           break; // not found(already processed), or orphan!
        }
        let index = o[0] == lastindex ? o[1] : o[0];  // no turn back!
        lastindex = index;
        coord = avert[index][0] === coord ? avert[index][1] : avert[index][0];
        hexa.push(coord);
    }
    if (j >= 6) { // found all vertices
        // check that the last coord is the starting point
        if (hexa[5] === origin) { // got it
             hexas.push( hexa );
             hexa.forEach(function(h){ // delete used vertices
                delete overt[h];
             });
        }
    }
});
```

All hexagons should be in `hexas`

Comment: Wow. I'm actually shocked how fast this algorithm is.
Using my approach it took about 3 Minutes.
Using your algorithm (with minor changes) it only takes 2-3 seconds.
Realy, really awesome. Thanks!

Comment: also very interesting approach. this really pushed my knowledge in coding (performant) algorithms.

Comment: Thank you David for your kind comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the nested loop over all data by using a hash map. Key the individual vertices with a hash, for instance their JSON representation, and store the corresponding x, y coordinate together with a list of neigbor objects.

Once you have that, it is easy to walk through that graph and identify the hexagons.

Runnable snippet using the sample data you provided:

```js
function findHexPolyPoints(stamps) {
    // Create graph
    let map = new Map;
    for (let {vertices} of stamps) {
        // Get unique identifier for each vertex (its JSON notation)
        let keys = vertices.map(JSON.stringify);
        // Create "nodes" for each vertex, keyed by their key
        let nodes = keys.map(function (key, i) {
            let {x, y} = vertices[i];
            let node = map.get(key);
            if (!node) map.set(key, node = { key, x, y, neighbors: [] });
            return node;
        });
        // Link these two nodes in both directions
        nodes[0].neighbors.push(nodes[1]);
        nodes[1].neighbors.push(nodes[0]);
    }
    
    // Walk through the graph to detect and collect hexagons
    let hexagons = [];
    for (let [key, vertex] of map) {
        let hexagon = [];
        while (vertex && hexagon.push(vertex) < 6) {
            vertex = vertex.neighbors.find(neighbor => !hexagon.includes(neighbor));
        }
        // Remove collected nodes so they don't get visited a second time
        for (let {key} of hexagon) map.delete(key);
        // Verify that they form indeed a hexagon:
        if (vertex && vertex.neighbors.includes(hexagon[0])) {
            // Simplify the hexagon to only coordinates (12 coordinates)
            hexagons.push(hexagon.flatMap(({x, y}) => [x, y]));
        }
    }
    return hexagons;
}

// Demo. Just replace `stamps` with your actual data.
const stamps = [{vertices: [{x: 114.5116411118, y: 342.9815785601},{x: 115.6663416502, y: 344.9815785601}]},{vertices: [{x: 115.6663416502, y: 340.9815785601},{x: 114.5116411118, y: 342.9815785601}]},{vertices: [{x: 122.6663416502, y: 364.9815785601},{x: 147.9757427269, y: 314.9815785601},]},{vertices: [{x: 117.9757427269, y: 340.9815785601},{x: 115.6663416502, y: 340.9815785601},]},{vertices: [{x: 119.1304432653, y: 342.9815785601},{x: 117.9757427269, y: 340.9815785601},]},{vertices: [{x: 117.9757427269, y: 344.9815785601},{x: 119.1304432653, y: 342.9815785601},]},{vertices: [{x: 115.6663416502, y: 344.9815785601},{x: 117.9757427269, y: 344.9815785601},]},];
let hexagons = findHexPolyPoints(stamps);
console.log(hexagons);
```

It is true that plain old `for` loops are somewhat faster than `.map`, `.forEach`, `.reduce`, `.find` and the likes, but here I kept using them, as the main speed up is really coming from using a hash map.